# SIlverlight WP7 switch screen

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

How to switch between screens programatically in silverlight on WP7 guys ?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/NextView.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Navigator to do this:

```
this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Views/Whatever.xaml"), UriKind.Relative));
```